# Simple question on SET theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a bit difficulty :

If A,B and C are sets then:

- A ∈ B , B ⊆ C.Then A ⊆ C is true.
- A ⊄ B.Then B ⊂ C is true.
- C ∈ p(A) iff C ⊆ A, where p(A) denotes the power of set A.

All are correct?It's confusing me alot.

Basically i am a CS student, very poor in maths, but now have to do it,
as maths is applicable everywhere.

Also please suggest me few tips and logics to study maths in a easy way.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first point **would** be correct if you either changed "$A\subseteq C$" to "$A\in C$", or changed "$A\in B$" to "$A\subseteq B$". The first change works because $B\subseteq C$ means every element of $B$ is an element of $C$, so if $A\in B$, then $A$ in $C$. The second change works because $A\subseteq B$ means every element of $A$ would be an element of $B$, so since every element of $B$ is an element of $C$, then every element of $A$ is an element of $C$, meaning $A\subseteq C$.

Your second point is incorrect. Knowing only that $A\not\subset B$ (that is, that some element of $A$ isn't in $B$) tells us *nothing* about whether all the elements of $B$ are all in $C$.

Your third point is correct. The $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is **defined** to be the set of all $C$ such that $C\subseteq A$. Thus, $C\subseteq A$ if and only if $C\in\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: So, what is given, the 1st point is incorrect?

Comment: As stated, it is incorrect. Given $A\in B$ and $B\subseteq C$, we can only conclude that $A\in C$ (by definition of the statement "$B\subseteq C$"), and not necessarily that $A\subseteq C$.

Comment: @joeyrohan My mistake. The first point is INCORRECT, I just read it wrong. You have my apologies.

Comment: Thank you :) Can you please just give me 2 more suggestions?1) how to use symbols like ⊆ , P or something, is there a simple way? 2) The latter part,how to study maths in a logical way? any help would be much appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: @joeyrohan I'd love to be able to tell you how to study maths in a logical way, but unfortunately I have yet to find one! Maybe check amazon for a highly rated introduction to logic? I presume there are works written for philosophy students, which should probably be accessible. Or buy a book about how to prove things. Again, search amazon.

Comment: @user18921 thank you!